# Cannot get form data within a textarea using scala-play post request

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a form with a text area inside it:

```html
<form action='postCode' method='post' id="code">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Integrated Development Environment</legend>
  <p>Write your assembly code here then hit the compile button.</p>
  <p>If there are errors it will return them; if not it will send you a file.</p>
  <textarea id="example_1" style="height: 550px; width: 99%;" name="asmCode" form="code">
    // This is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) for the EV3 robot's assembly language.


    vmthread main {
      // Put code inside here

      // This is an example:

      DATA16 C4
      MOVE16_16(262,C4)
      SOUND(TONE,50,C4,300)
      SOUND_READY
    }
  </textarea>

  <br>
  <p>Commands:
    <input type='submit' value='Compile' />
    <input type='button' value='Get Binary' />
  </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And I am trying to get the input from the user using a post request but whenever I try to do so I just get the text already inside the textarea. My controller looks like this:

```scala
import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

import akka.stream.Materializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import play.api.http.ContentTypes
import play.api.libs.Comet
import play.api.libs.json._

import scala.sys.process._
import java.io._
import scala.language.postfixOps

/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page.
   *
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def getCode() = Action { request =>
    var code = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded

    code.map { args =>
      val code = args("asmCode").head
      val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("asm.lms"))
      pw.write(code)
      // if(("java -jar assembler.jar asm"!!).length() > 30) {
      //   if (("java -jar assembler.jar asm"!!).substring(0,30).contains("bytes")) {
      //     println("Yeah")
      //   }
      // } else if (("java -jar assembler.jar asm"!!).contains("bytes")) {
      //     println("Yeah")
      // } else {
      //   println("no")
      // }
      println("java -jar assembler.jar asm"!!)

      if(("java -jar assembler.jar asm"!!).length() > 10){
        println("java -jar assembler.jar asm"!!)
      }
    }.getOrElse(Ok("An unknown error has occured. Whoops!"))
    Ok("")
  }
}
```

And my routes file looks like this:

```scala
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index()
+ nocsrf
POST    /postCode                   controllers.HomeController.getCode()
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

I am just trying to get the form data within the textarea but it always sends the same thing even after I edit the contents of the textarea before sending it in the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, my print to file function was not working properly.